# Peculiar compile error: ‘cap’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I am getting a compile time error that seems to defy all my logic. The following three code snippets work, while the third does not. Why?

**Works 1**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

cv::VideoCapture cap(0); 

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

**Works 2**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Works 3**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap; 
    cap.open(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Does not work:**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

cv::VideoCapture cap; 
cap.open(0);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> error: ‘cap’ does not name a type  cap.open(0);

GCC version: `6.1.1 20160501` 
OpenCV version: `3.1.0-3`

What could be wrong?

Comment: Because C++ doesn't allow writing procedure in such way outside functions?

Comment: Just put `cap.open(0);` inside the main

Comment: Slightly simplified: Only declarations can occur in that position. The first part of a declaration is the name of a type. Thus, 'cap' must name a type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `cap.open(0)` outside of `main` as this is how C++ works. But `cap.open(0)` inside `main` will work just fine.

And as a general rule, you cannot write this kind of code outside a function, the compiler is simply not able to understand where to execute it during run-time.